# Error while setting a django project on IIS

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, iis

I was following [these steps](http://codesmartinc.com/2013/04/12/running-django-in-iis7iis8/) for setting up django on IIS8. I got till the end of the documentation but when i ran the localhost on port 8003, i was getting the following error:

Error occurred while reading WSGI handler:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Django\[myprojname]\wfastcgi.py", line 710, in main
    env, handler = read_wsgi_handler(response.physical_path)
  File "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Django\[myprojname]\wfastcgi.py", line 567, in read_wsgi_handler
    return env, get_wsgi_handler(handler_name)
  File "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Django\[myprojname]\wfastcgi.py", line 538, in get_wsgi_handler
    handler = getattr(handler, name)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'wsgi'


StdOut: 

StdErr:
```

Can anyone let me know why it wouldn't give me the same output as shown in the tutorial?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently `pip install django` does not set the proper permissions for IIS to use the libraries it downloaded.

You need to find your Python folder (C:\python27 by default) and forcibly reset the permissions, i.e. `Replace all child object permissions with inheritable permissions from this object` as shown here: 
https://serverfault.com/questions/475612/replace-permission-entries-on-all-child-objects-using-icacls